# Existe una pregunta sobre Y, ¿debemos pedir al usuario que haga una nueva pregunta sobre X?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-propia

En relación a la pregunta [Clausula COUNT(1) y DENSE_RANK()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/34696/21), resulta ser un caso del clásico [problema xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/149992).

El usuario por fin se da cuenta (gracias a los comentarios) y ahora por fin queda claro cual es el problema X.

Sin embargo, durante el proceso existe ya una [<strike>buena</strike> respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34714/21) para **Y** (quito *buena* porque la respuesta es mía).

Actualmente también existe ya una [buena respuesta para X](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34726/21)

En mi opinión lo correcto es pedir al usuario que deje la pregunta original como estaba y que **formule una nueva pregunta para X**. Esto dejaría espacio para que la respuesta ya escrita (que algún tiempo y esfuerzo ha llevado) persista, y dar lugar a mover o publicar nuevas respuestas para el verdadero problema en otro hilo.

¿Que piensa la comunidad de esto?

Comment: En esta pregunta se cuestiona lo mismo: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/811/pregunta-editada-por-el-usuario-qu%C3%A9-hacer-con-la-respuesta-anterior aunque no hacen referencia al problemaXY. En mi opinión la primera pregunta es mas clara que esta. ¿Debería marcarse esta pregunta como duplicada?

Comment: @toledano, en mi opinión no es necesariamente el mismo caso. La pregunta a la que haces referencia habla de un cambio como _evolución_ de la pregunta, esto no necesariamente se da por tratarse del problema XY.

Answer (score 2):

A mí esto también me ha pasado en algunas ocasiones. Y es bastante molesto.

Más que nada porque el OP realiza una pregunta y tu te esfuerzas en contestarla. Le das una respuesta y entonces al OP le surge una nueva duda, con lo cual edita la pregunta editando todo lo anterior para dar paso a la nueva pregunta.

El problema es aún más grande cuando hay otros usuarios que también le responden pero esta vez a la segunda pregunta, por lo tanto las respuestas de la primera pregunta parecen no tener validez.

En estos casos hago dos cosas:

- En caso de que nadie haya respondido aún a la segunda pregunta le pido por favor que deje la pregunta tal y como estaba y realice una nueva pregunta con las nuevas dudas.
- En caso de que haya dos tipos de respuestas (para la primera pregunta y para la segunda), como ambas tienen igual validez, le pido al OP que por favor deje ambas preguntas para que las respuestas que responden a la primera pregunta no pierdan su validez.

Comment: Ah... ya entendí! Esta pregunta ya se había hecho. En cuanto la encuentre pego el enlace.

Comment: El problema de dejar ambas preguntas es que se "viola" la regla del sitio: Una pregunta por pregunta. Con esto ya no existe respuesta canónica y sería posible elegir la respuesta correcta para el OP, puesto que potencialmente habrá una respuesta correcta para cada pregunta/problema planteado. Por eso digo que en mi opinión debiera dividirse en dos preguntas.

Comment: @jachguate Sí, en la mía también. El problema es que si ambas respuestas están correctas, creo que se debería marcar como correcta la primera y valorar ambas. Sin embargo, no puedes perjudicar tampoco al que ha hecho un esfuerzo por contestar a la segunda pregunta. Tendría que haber alguna manera de migrar a una nueva pregunta las respuestas para dicha pregunta dejando la original tal y como estaba.

Answer (score 2):

Para contestar tu pregunta, primero quiero distinguir 2 situaciones que se parecen, pero no son lo mismo (porque creo que no todos entendieron la pregunta):

1. OP hace una pregunta. OP recibe una respuesta que corrige su problema. Pero ahora que ha resuelto su primer problema, ahora surge un nuevo problema o una nueva duda. En vez de aceptar la respuesta, OP modifica su pregunta para plantear su nuevo problema, invalidando la respuesta original.

   En este caso, es obvio que OP debería aceptar la respuesta y escribir una pregunta separada para su nuevo problema.

   Esta es la situación descrita en la respuesta de @Error404, pero me parece que no es la situación descrita en tu pregunta.
2. OP hace una pregunta de baja calidad donde la descripción en la pregunta se enfoca mas en lo que OP cree que es la solución (Y: ejemplo - *no logro que el martillo me funcione...*) en vez de realmente explicar su verdadero problema con los detalles pertinentes (X: ejemplo - *necesito meter el tornillo en este hueco*. O sea que el problema no es el martillo en sí, sino que no debería usar un martillo en esta situación...)

   En este caso, hasta que no se le pida a OP de aclarar mas la pregunta, el problema X no se entiende.

Tu pregunta concierne la segunda situación.

Mi opinión es que cuando un usuario cae en el error de hacer un pregunta del tipo XY, usualmente los expertos (como lo eres tu en SQL, de eso no hay ninguna duda) tienen la capacidad de percibir que el usuario no está formulando la pregunta correcta.  Aunque es posible contestar la pregunta Y rápidamente, si yo puedo percibir que en realidad hay un problema X que OP no ha logrado expresar, me parece que tengo la responsabilidad de guiar OP a mejorar su pregunta para que salga el problema X a la luz.

Tal vez esto implique ser un poco pacientes antes de contestar a la pregunta y concentrarse mas bien en pedir aclaraciones y mas detalles en los comentarios, y esperar que OP agregue esos detalles antes de contestar.

En otras palabras, si sospechamos que OP ha caído en el error de la pregunta XY, creo que es preferible ayudar a OP a formular la pregunta X mas bien que contestar la pregunta Y. Haciéndolo de esta manera evitará "perder" una buena respuesta cuando la pregunta se aclare, y será mas útil para OP.

Comment: No olvides que uno de los fines que se persigue en SO es crear una fuente de conocimiento para futuras consultas. Visto desde ese punto de vista, hay casos donde conviene tanto responder Y como X, puesto que ambas serán de utilidad. X para el OP, y Y para casos futuros donde Y sea aplicable.

Comment: Lo que dices es muy cierto. Obviamente, cada caso es único. Porque, por otro lado, he notado que muy a menudo (y no estoy hablando del ejemplo que pusistes) hay preguntas Y que sin aclarar la X son de muy poca utilidad o se prestan a respuestas que simplemente *adivinan* el problema. Si el fin es, como dices, de crear una fuente de conocimiento para futuros lectores, vale la pena tomar el tiempo de educar a los que preguntan a que lo hagan claramente. Y, a veces, la manera de lograrlo es de no contestar hasta que mejoren la pregunta. Si no, la siguiente pregunta seguirá el mismo patrón.